# Android custom URI for launch OS features

Tags: android, uri, qr-code

I have custom URI scheme like this => `intent://#Intent;package=com.android.provider.Settings.System;end`
with this URI I want to launch for example System Settings, but when I scan this with QR scanner it throws error that this aplication not installed...

Tested on android 5.1[image: QR-code for launching settings]

So any advices or documentation will be considered

Answer (score 0):

That will not work.

Application should have correct `intent-filter` in `Android Manifest`. So `com.android.provider.Settings.System` just dont have it. After you tried to launch it by `intent://#Intent;package=com.android.provider.Settings.System;end` OS tried to find registered intent-filter for that package, didnt find it and throwed error.

[Official documentation:](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html)

> When you create an implicit intent, the Android system finds the
>   appropriate component to start by comparing the contents of the intent
>   to the intent filters declared in the manifest file of other apps on
>   the device. If the intent matches an intent filter, the system starts
>   that component and delivers it the Intent object.

The only way to open `com.android.provider.Settings.System` is to write your own app with corrent `intent-filter`, handle deep link and run `intent` inside your app.